# Replace a substring but not the entire string

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a YAML file, `schema.yml`, with some values ​​like:

```
{{CODE}}-project
{{CODE}}-project-start
```

If I use

```
REP="s/{{CODE}}-project/123-project"
cat schema.yml | sed "$REP"
```

it will replace both `{{CODE}}-project` and `{{CODE}}-project-start`.
How can I replace only `{{CODE}}-project` occurrences but not `{{CODE}}-project-start` occurrences?

Comment: Does that help? `REP="s/{{CODE}}-project$/123-project/"`

Comment: See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: @tink Did you look at the answers there? They use `\<` and `\>`, but this will match before `-` so it won't solve this problem.

Comment: The links do not solves this issue...

Answer (score 0):

Use anchors:

```
sed 's/^{{CODE}}-project$/123-project/' file
```

Or skip the substitution if something else is matched on the line; in this case `-start`:

```
sed '/-start/! s/^{{CODE}}-project/123-project/' file
```

Or Perl with a negative lookahead:

```
perl -lpe 's/^{{CODE}}-project(?!-start)/123-project/' file
```

All print:

```
123-project
{{CODE}}-project-start
```

---

Btw: using `cat` is not necessary to feed input into `sed`. Better to read the file directly.